# How do I get the changes from a branch in git without the commits?

Tags: git

I'm looking for a less rubbish way of doing this:

```
git diff patch.DisableCreditCheck > ~/patch
patch -p1 < ~/patch
```

ie. The changes from a branch as raw uncommitted changes.

The downside of patch is that it isn't very clever; for example I often get "Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected! Assume -R[n]?" when there isn't any previous patch, it just happens that there's a set of filenames that it gets confused by.

It'd be *much* nicer to be able to do this:

```
git merge --no-commit --no-ff patch.DisableCreditCheck
```

...but that leaves you in a merge state, with no obvious way to get back to being in a normal state while preserving the changes.

Help! Any decent way of doing this?

(This is a very useful thing to be able to do when you're sharing patches on the code youre working on; much MUCH better than having a set of patch files to pass around)

Edit: As an example of what I'm trying to achieve, lets say we have two branches, master, and config.me.

When I do git diff config.me > ~/patch; patch -p1 < ~/patch the result is:

```
$ git status
# On branch master
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#       modified:   Web/Web.config
#
```

This is the desired outcome... but without using patch, which doesn't work well (specifically on windows it seems incredibly bad at detecting changes that should merge perfectly, but instead it'll get confused and write out a bunch of .orig and .rej files).

So, like I said; I want the changes from a branch *without the commits* as local *uncommitted changes*.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're asking.  Would you like to preserve the commits?  Have you looked at [git bundle](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-bundle)?

Comment: @jszakmeister No, I specifically do NOT want to preserve the commits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first example shows that you don't want the *changes* (i.e. commit deltas) of a particular branch, but rather you want your working-tree to *reflect the latest state* of that branch.  (A subtle difference that can cause of confusion when trying to pick the right commands.)

Few ways:

**Method 1:**

```
$ git checkout patch.DisableCreditCheck .
```

This gets your working-tree to mirror `patch.DisableCreditCheck`.  Changes between `HEAD` an `patch.DisableCreditCheck` are automatically staged.  Word of caution: It'll also blow away any uncommitted changes in your working-tree.  (Note: that period (`.`) needs to be the path to the root of your working-tree.)

**Method 2:**

```
$ git read-tree patch.DisableCreditCheck
```

This gets your *index* to mirror `patch.DisableCreditCheck`, but leaves your working-tree as is.

**Method 3:**

```
$ git checkout --detached patch.DisableCreditCheck
$ git reset your-original-branch
$ git checkout -B your-original-branch
```

This is a silly method that's roughly the same as *Method 1*.  It's included for academy and because it might be a little easier to follow.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways:

**First**, if you want the changes from `branchA` but don't want them to be committed in branch `branchB`:

```
>> git checkout branchB
>> git cherry-pick -n ..branchA
```

This will get all commits that happened "in between B and A" but doesn't commit them. `git status` will show a bunch of changed files.

**Secondly**, if you want to have the changes in a new commit but not necessarily *every single commit you made*:

```
>> git checkout branchA
>> git rebase -i branchB
```

This will rebase your branch `A` ontop of `B` but will let you chose wich commits to `pick` and wich ones to `squash`. Squashing will essentially collapse several commits into a single, bigger one. See `git help rebase` for more info on squashing.

Comment: didn't seem to work unfortunately. "$ git cherry-pick -n ..config.me
error: Commit 190b2139b728b8f607e921346e61ee2adaefb2de is a merge but no -m option was given.
fatal: cherry-pick failed". Using rebase brings the commits across, which isn't what I want.

Comment: That said, cherry picking looks exactly like what I want. I just can't figure out how to use it. :P

Comment: Alternatively you could do `git rebase -i branchB`, set all but the last commit to `squash` and then `git reset --soft HEAD^`. It will pull all commits to your branch, stuff them into one single commit and then undo that commit while leaving the files the way they were.